# Empty mysqld.log after fresh Mysql 5.7 install on Centos 7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

After fresh install of MySQL 5.7 on Centos 7 the file /var/log/mysqld.log is created, but is empty. There is no temporary password so I can't proceed with using MySQL.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I had to start the mysqld server after installation in order the log to be populated.

Comment: only after the service is started we can get the password wity:
grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log